# How to get only one item of a subdocument in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
ASchema={item:[BSchema]};
ASchema.findOne({item._id=xx})
```

It gets a array of BSchema, document.item is a array. how to get only one item which _id is xx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator using query projection to just return your matched array element. For Mongoose you can do this:

```
ASchema.findOne({"item._id": itemId},"item.$",function(err,doc) {
    console.log( doc );
});
```

Or paired in an object:

```
ASchema.findOne({"item._id": itemId},{ "item.$": 1 },function(err,doc) {
    console.log( doc );
});
```

Mongoose supports the shorthand syntax with options like "-fieldname" for field removal which is the same as `{ "fieldname": 0 }`. But you cannot mix inclusion and exclusion with the exception of the root `_id` field.

Therefore you must specify all of the fields you want to appear when using projection.

See also [`.select()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) in the mongoose documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax for the query is wrong. Try:

```
ASchema.findOne({'item._id': xx})
```

This link is helpful for more examples: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: The same. BSchema is a subdocument of ASchema, BSchema doesn't save in  its collection, it saved in ASchema's subdocument, like {item:[{_id:1},{_id:2}]

Comment: What is ASchema.findOne({'item._id': xx}) returning for you right now? BTW are you expecting to get a query object? If you were expecting the result you should pass a callback.

Comment: ```Lists.findOne({"item._id": itemId
        }).exec(function(err, docList) {
        var odds = docList.item.odds;
        console.log("odd:" + odds);
      });```docList.item is a array,like docList.item[0],docList.item[1],but docList.item.odds is undefined,only docList.item[0].adds is right. I have to forEach the array to check which item is I want.

Comment: Ok, forgive me if this is totally ignorant, but if docList.item is an array. Where is the docList.item.odds property coming from?

Comment: Also - you should update your question with this additional information. I think it would be helpful for others trying to help you.